# Por que usar .length no for?

Tags: javascript

Eae , Eu estou estudando pelo livro JS Guia Definitivo e estou vendo muitos exemplos onde e usado length em 'for', e eu estou em duvida por que usar o length se (pelo que eu sei) ele só pega o comprimento se for uma string. EX:

```
var x = 15
var y = 'haha'
console.log(x.length) // Undefined
console.log(y.length) // 4
```

**Exemplo do Livro**

```
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) { // Para cada índice no array
var key = keys[i]; // Obtém a chave nesse índice
values[i] = o[key]; // Armazena o valor no array values
}
```

Entao porque usar o length como no exemplo acima ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse caso `keys` deve ser um [Array](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arranjo_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)).

Por exemplo:

```js
const keys1 = ['key1', 'key2']
// keys1.length === 2

const keys2 = Object.keys({ key1: 10, key2: 20, key3: 10 });
// keys2.length === 3
```